# primeng p-dropdown inside p-table, on change of one dropdown changes all dropdown values inside the table

Tags: angular, primeng

I need to have dropdown inside the table
Dropdown in very row of column is populated from the same list(database table)
My Issue

On change the dropdownvalue of one p-dropdown (say at row position 3) all the other p-dropdowns within the p-table gets changed to that value.
I am new to primeng & angular as well and not able to figure out the issue.
My current code , and am stuck how to proceed to handle dropdown selection to impact in its specific row

```
<p-table [value]="signals" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
        
        <th>Signal Code</th>
        <th>Signal Name</th>
        <th>Master Device</th>
      </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-car>
      <tr>
        
        <td>{{car.code}}</td>
        <td>{{car.name}}</td>
        <td>
          
          <p-dropdown [options]="devices"
               [(ngModel)]="seleDevice" optionLabel="name">

          </p-dropdown>
        </td>

      </tr>
    </ng-template>

  </p-table>
```

ts file code below

```
export class DeviceSignalComponent implements OnInit {
...
...
public devices: Device[];
public signals: Signal[];
public seleDevice: Device;
...
...

getData() {
...
...
this.devices = <<call service for data from DB>>
this.signals = <<call service for data from DB>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-table-dropdown

import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/api';
selectedOperand : SelectItem;
operandNames = [
                    {code: 'GREATERTHAN', name: 'Greater than'},
                    {code: 'LESSTHAN', name: 'Less than'},
                    {code: 'GREATERTHANOREQUAL', name: 'Greater than or equal'},
                    {code: 'LESSTHANOREQUAL', name: 'Less than or equal'},
                    {code: 'EQUAL', name: 'Equal to'},
                    {code: 'NONE', name: 'None'}
                 ]; 

  operands: SelectItem[] = this.operandNames.map((name) => {
    return { label: name.name, value: name.code }
  }); 

 public onChangeOperand(limit: LimitModel) {
    const index = this.selectedLimits.indexOf(limit);
    if (index == -1) {
      this.selectedLimits.push(limit);
    }
  }
```

/*html*/